# java selenium leaving zombie processes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm setting up a test suite to hit some internal (and eventually external [production] to replace pingdom), but right now when I run it in eclipse, every other invocation of "Run as Java Application" just hangs, leaves a few zombie processes, and output nothing (I guess obvious from the hangs portion). But if I kill it (still in Eclipse), and restart, it immediately outputs the page and leaves no zombie process. So to visualize, it works this way:

1. Run as java application works, and prints out what I'd expect
2. Run as java application hangs and does pretty much nothing (except produce zombie processes)
3. Run as java application works, and prints out what I'd expect
4. Run as java application hangs and does pretty much nothing (except produce zombie processes)
5. ...

```
Jerry$ ps -ef | grep -i headless | wc
      16     511   15011
Jerry$ ps -ef | grep -i headless | wc
      21     678   19990
Jerry$ ps -ef | grep -i headless | wc
      21     678   19990
Jerry$ ps -ef | grep -i headless | wc
      26     845   24977
```

I had tried it a few times so you can see it starts with 16 and after a handful of runs, it's now at 26 zombie (orphaned?) processes still running in the background.

Now, the code:

```
public class SeleniumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Globally set the driver location
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");

        // Locally pass in the options
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

        // Create the driver, download, and test
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

        driver.get("http://192.168.2.15:8080/testApp/m/getBeans2");
        
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

        // This block was introduced around the 21 mark as I was testing if I had to 
        // quit first between subsequent calls, so calling it twice didn't lead to the
        // initial 16 zombie processes, just the call to the QA server above
        System.out.println("--------------------   LOCALHOST   --------------------");
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/testApp/m/getBeans2");

        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Right now I'm using Open JDK 11, Chrome Driver 95.0.4638.69, and this version of selenium:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

So...why am I getting the Zombies/orphaned processes - is this something I just have to clean up in between runs?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: @Prophet The focus would be the main question, i.e., the title; if you think it would get others to answer, I can remove the follow up questions, but no one has even attempted

Answer (score 0):

The exact cause remains unknown (in the question up above, I say every other call fails, that part remains unknown), but the Test was a bit too simple (it was destined to get more complex and useful, and had I continued building out the final version of the test class and testing then versus testing/examining every step of the way, I wouldn't have even noticed), meaning, if Selenium throws an exception, the **driver.quit()** isn't called, so the process lives on.

So adding these lines to the code above, "fixes" it, name, set some timeouts and catch exception

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

    try {
        driver.get(url);
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        // do something useful here
        System.err.println("Error with the driver");
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        driver.quit();
```